# The signature key was not found, Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience is invalid"

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, access-token, azure-ad-msal, bearer-token

My React application is registered in Azure. I use MSAL for user authentication and call secured API, however I get below error while calling the API

> Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"
> Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience is invalid"

I pass application client id to class PublicClientApplication of @azure/msal-browser library and gets a ID Token which is passed while calling the API.

It works fine when I use another application client id. Hence, I compared the manifest file of both apps and they are exactly same!

I tried with access token instead of id token, but gives error

> "Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"

what could be missing?

When I use other application's client id in my react app, I get the token which is passed as a Bearer token to the API and it works fine. Hence I tried to compare the settings of the another working app but no difference.